# Can a Constructor in a Class have more than 1 super()? (Java or GWT)

Tags: java, gwt

I have this class `public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>`. I want that class to `super` different objects depending on different key variable.

The following code is ok but it only have 1 `super (new ClickableTextCell())`

```
public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>{
   private final int index;
   public IndexedColumn(int index) {
       super(new ClickableTextCell());
       this.index = index;
   }

   @Override
   public String getValue(List<String> object) {
       return object.get(this.index);
   }

   public int getIndex(){
       return index;
   }
}
```

In other class

```
int myIndx=getIndex();
IndexedColumn nameColumn=null;
if(text.equals("clickText")){
     nameColumn=new IndexedColumn(myIndx);
}
```

However, if i want to both `super(new ClickableTextCell())` & `super(new ButtonCell())` , then it got error

```
public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>{
   private final int index;
   public IndexedColumn(int index, int cellType) {
       if(cellType==1)
          super(new ClickableTextCell());
       else{
          super(new ButtonCell());
       }
       this.index = index;
   }
}
```

So the eclipse suggested me to have another constructor like this:

```
public class IndexedColumn extends Column<List<String>, String>{
   private final int index;
   public IndexedColumn(int index) {
       super(new ClickableTextCell());
       this.index = index;
   }  

   public IndexedColumn(int index, int forNothingKey) {
       super(new ButtonCell());
       this.index = index;
   }  

}
```

then in other class

```
int myIndx=getIndex();
IndexedColumn nameColumn=null;
if(text.equals("clickText")){
     nameColumn=new IndexedColumn(myIndx);
}
else if(text.equals("clickButton")){
     int forNoGoodReason=1;
     nameColumn=new IndexedColumn(myIndx, forNoGoodReason);
}
```

As you can see, in order to be able to use `ButtonCell` column, i have to use an `int forNoGoodReason` variable for nothing.

Is it a good practice to do that?

or can you find a better way to fix it?

Comment: How about `super(cellType==1?new ClickableTextCell():new ButtonCell())`. Not exactly the most readable but it should work. I would suggest `static` factory methods in preference.

Comment: what is i want 3 super or 4 super?

Comment: @BoristheSpider +1 about the static factory method.  I don't think your first idea will work, though, unless the superclass has a constructor with an `Object` parameter, or some other class that's a superclass of both `ClickableTextCell` and `ButtonCell`.  That is, the compiler has to be able to pick *one* superclass constructor that fits the expression.  This can't be used to select between two superclass constructors at run time, based on my testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the superclass of a class is explicitly declared in the class header; e.g.

```
  public class Foo extends Bar ... {
     ....
  }
```

Every class apart from `Object` has exactly one superclass determined at compile time.  It cannot be changed or selected dynamically / at runtime.

GWT, being based on Java and the Java type system has the same restriction.

---

On the other hand, you can declare a class with multiple constructors like this:

```
public class Bar ... {
     public Bar (Integer i) { ... }
     public Bar (Double d) { ... }
}
```

and do this:

```
public class Foo extends Bar ... {
     public Foo (Integer i) {
        super(i);
        ...
     }
     public Foo (Double d) {
        super(d);
        ...
     }
}
```

But, you cannot do anything like this:

```
public class Foo extends Bar ... {
     public Foo (Integer i, Double d, boolean b) {
        super(b ? i : d);
        ...
     }
}
```

The problem is that the the `super` call in a constructor must resolve to a single constructor overload in the superclass *at compile time*, based on the static types of the arguments provided to the `super` call.

The only way to get something like this if you are going to use `new` to create objects is to have a unified constructor in the superclass that handles both / all cases; e.g.

```
public class Bar ... {
     public Bar (Object o) {
         if (o instanceof Integer) {
             ...
         } else if (o instanceof Double) {
             ...
         } // etcetera
     }
}
```

... but that is exceedingly ugly, not to mention the fragility, and harmful coupling.

The other alternative is to use a factory method ... like this:

```
public class Foo extends Bar ... {
     public Foo (Integer i) {
        super(i);
        ...
     }
     public Foo (Double d) {
        super(d);
        ...
     }

     public static Foo createFoo(Integer i, Double d, boolean b) {
        return b ? new Foo(i) : new Foo(d);
     }
}
```

Comment: I think the question was about multiple superclass _constructors_, not multiple superclasses.

Comment: Yea ... I realized that.

Comment: @Stephen, i tested "super(cellType==1?new ClickableTextCell():new ButtonCell())" & it work fine in GWT, so what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Tum there is nothing wrong with it *if you have a constructor whose argument type is a supertype of `ClickableTextCell` and `ButtonCell`*.  (And I even included an example in my Answer!!!)  But if you don't, the Java compiler will reject it.